# mongodb - query to return first match record from list of params

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongo collection where i have below structure:

```
{
   "feature":"abc",
   "translations"[
      {
         "lang":"en",
         "text":"This is my text in english"
      },
      {
         "lang":"de",
         "text":"This is my text in german"
      }
   ]
},
{
   "feature":"cde",
   "translations"[
      {
         "lang":"en",
         "text":"This is my text in english"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, i want to write query to return default language "en" text if particular language ie., de text not found for a particular feature. If both language texts present, only "de" lang text need to be returned and "en" need to be ignored.

I tried with `$or` or `$in`, but these are giving both lang texts if present for a feature. I'm okay to do minimal changes to mongo document structure if required for better results.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've think for this is using aggreagtion creating an auxiliar array (to get data easier) where is stored the transalation in desired language.

If the array is not empty, language exists, so the output is that value, otherwise, language will be english.

This is the query I've done, hope it helps.

- First create a new filed using `$set` filtering values where "language = de". Using aggregation is neccesary use `$filter` because `$elemMatch` is not allowed.
- Then, the next stage can use our auxiliar array to get `$size` and values. If the auxiliar array has not values (size is 0) then the desired language is english, stored in `$translations.text`. Else the language will be that one stored in the auxiliar array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "aux_translations": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$translations",
          "as": "l",
          "cond": {"$eq": ["$$l.lang","de"]}}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "translation": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {"$eq": [{"$size": "$aux_translations"},0]},
          "then": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$translations.text",0]},
          "else": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$aux_translations.text",0]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J7-W5IagPKe)

Comment: I ran your script. But its giving both 'de' and 'en' in results. But i need only 'de' if exists for a feature ('abc'), otherwise it has to return 'en'. I mean if i pass feature as 'cde' and lang as 'de', it should give me the result of 'en' as 'de' not found for 'cde' feature.